# Speed of sound from a moving Cart

Tags: waves, reference-frames, acoustics, inertial-frames

I was just wondering about whether sound behaves as light or not. Say I am in a moving cart moving with a speed of 100m/s.
I shout something in the direction of motion of the cart. Would sound travel at 343m/s or at 443m/s from the ground frame. (Assuming sound travels at 343m/s in ground frame)

PS:- I am new to this community, so apologies for any mistakes whatsoever.

Comment: Hi, sound would keep traveling at its speed, let's say $343\frac{m}{s}$, because it is a wave, not some object you are throwing (so that velocities add up). This is why you have shock waves when something is traveling at roughly the speed of sound. 
You can imagine that at every moment in time you are producing a spherical wave, and the net effect is a convolution of these waves.

Comment: By the way this is what happens with light as well when you observe Cherenkov radiation for example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of sound in a medium is relative to the velocity of the medium, not the velocity of the source. If the air is stationary with respect to the ground and the speed of sound in the air is 343m/s, the shout propagates at 343m/s relative to the ground regardless of the motion of the cart.

Answer (score 0):

$343m/s$. sound travels at 343m/s relative to air. The speed cannot change if the medium is still. And I think that air is still with respect to ground and therfore relative velocity of sound with ground would be 343m/s. The concept of light is completely different.  What you actually wanted to ask was " is the relative velocity of sound with you(moving at 100m/s) is 343m/s or 443m/s ?"  And the answer then would be 443m/s for the wave moving behind you and 243m/s for moving in front of you.